# Miss matching between the username and the password

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, credentials

First of all, I created two different facebook accounts as mentioned below:

Account #1
Username: AbdTestFacebook1@gmail.com
Password: paycash

Account # 2
Username: AbdTestFacebook2@gmail.com
Password: forthisbug

Scenario

1. Log into account #1 (which is AbdTestFacebook1@gmail.com) by using password #1 (which is “paycash”)
2. Log out from Account #1
3. Log into account #2 (which is AbdTestFacebook2@gmail.com) by using password #2 (which is “forthisbug”)
4. Log out from Account #2
5. Now Log into account #2 (which is AbdTestFacebook2@gmail.com) by using password #1 (which is “paycash”) , it logs into the account#1 successfully  Error it should not log in

I don't know if this is a problem. You can try this by yourself. I reported to Facebook, they told me it is not a problem.

Any idea?

Comment: You are only allowed to have one account according to Facebook Terms of Service. And it needs to have your name

Comment: do you think this is answer